# terraform destroy and then recreate policy assignment

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-policy

Hi I have a module with custom policy definiton and assignment, what I notice is if I make change to something else, without touching this policy module, and redeploy the whole terraform, Terraform is attempting to destroy the policy assignment, then recreate it.
because we have a monitoring rule, when policy assignment is activated, it sends out unnecessary alerts.
I only noticed this for custom policy definition and assignment, for built-in policy assignment, it's not happening. How can we fix/avoid this?

```
resource "azurerm_policy_definition" "auditresourcetag" {
  name         = "Audit if either of required tag is missing from a resource"
  policy_type  = "Custom"
  mode         = "Indexed"
  display_name = "Audit if either of required tag is missing from a resource"

  metadata = jsonencode(
    {
      "category" : "Tags"
  })

  policy_rule = jsonencode(
    {
      "if" : {
        "anyOf" : [
          {
            "field" : "tags[Application]",
            "exists" : false
          },
          {
            "field" : "tags[Environment]",
            "exists" : false
          },
          {
            "field" : "tags[Managedby]",
            "exists" : false
          }
        ]
      },
      "then" : {
        "effect" : "audit"
      }
  })

}

resource "azurerm_policy_assignment" "auditresourcetag" {
  name                 = "Audit if either of required tag is missing from a resource"
  scope                = var.scope
  policy_definition_id = azurerm_policy_definition.auditresourcetag.id
  description          = "Policy Assignment created via an Acceptance Test"
  display_name         = "Audit if either of required tag is missing from a resource"

  metadata = <<METADATA
    {
    "category": "Tags"
    }
METADATA

}
```

from terraform plan, it shows

```
# module.mcs_optimise_azure.module.azure_policy[0].azurerm_policy_assignment.auditresourcetag must be replaced
-/+ resource "azurerm_policy_assignment" "auditresourcetag" {
        description          = "Policy Assignment created via an Acceptance Test"
        display_name         = "Audit if either of required tag is missing from a resource"
              - updatedBy = null -> null
              - updatedOn = null -> null
            }
        )
        name                 = "Audit if either of required tag is missing from a resource"
      - not_scopes           = [] -> null
        policy_definition_id = "/subscriptions/***/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/Audit if either of required tag is missing from a resource"
      ~ scope                = "/subscriptions/***" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement

      + identity {
          + principal_id = (known after apply)
          + tenant_id    = (known after apply)
          + type         = (known after apply)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does terraform tell you why it needs to replace the resource?

Comment: I have uploaded terraform plan

Comment: Is the subscription in the scope correct?

Comment: Hi @Tobias, yeah scope has been set to scope                     = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id, when I call this module, it's never changed, I'm not sure why terraform thinks it needs replacement

Comment: Does changing the default `not_scopes` from `null` to `[]` change anything?